# Is there any need to use both wp_reset_postdata and wp_reset_query together?

Tags: theme-development, loop, query, reset, wp-reset-postdata

Is there any need to use both `wp_reset_postdata()` and `wp_reset_query()` together?

Is it a case that I would pick one of the two functions; is there any point in doing this after a query :

```
 wp_reset_postdata();
 wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use them both.

You should only use `wp_reset_query()`, if you modified query with `query_posts()` (which you should avoid). This function also call `wp_reset_postdata()` - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/query.php#L95

So it's better to use `wp_reset_postdata()` after running separate query.