# wp_reset_postdata() or wp_reset_query() after a custom loop?

Tags: wp-reset-postdata, wp-reset-query

Reading some stuff about `query_reset_postdata` and `query_reset_query` makes me confused. For example:

> 1. [Is there any need to use both wp_reset_postdata and wp_reset_query together?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62144/is-there-any-need-to-use-both-wp-reset-postdata-and-wp-reset-query-together)
> 2. http://www.poststat.us/properly-reset-wordpress-query/

Above states that you should only use `query_reset_postdata()` when using "separate queries".
In example2 there's a comment:

```
WP_Query( $args ) = wp_reset_postdata();
```

AND

```
query_posts ( $args ) = wp_reset_query();
```

And really you should never use `wp_reset_query` because you shouldn't use query_posts!?

In the WP Codex it states that you should use `wp_reset_query()` after a custom loop (first example) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Is the codex wrong then?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The difference between the two is that

- `wp_reset_query()` - ensure that the main query has been reset to the original main query
- `wp_reset_postdata()` - ensures that the global `$post` has been restored to the current post in the main query.

Indeed, looking at the [source](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_reset_query/) you'll see that the `wp_reset_query()` calls `wp_reset_postdata()`. The only difference between the two then is this line:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
```

(in `wp_reset_query()`). So `wp_reset_query()` is only necessary should those two globals differ, and that only happens if `query_posts()` has been used somewhere.

#### When should I use them?

Simply put:

- `wp_reset_postdata()` - immediately after every custom `WP_Query()`
- `wp_reset_query()` - immediately after every loop using `query_posts()`

#### Should I use wp_reset_query

Well, yes, but it's only needed after using `query_posts()`. As you've pointed out you [should never use `query_posts()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762). So if you aren't ever using `query_posts()` then it's *not necessary* to call `wp_reset_query()` (instead of `wp_reset_postdata()`.

In short, it's not that you shouldn't use `wp_reset_query()` instead of `wp_reset_postdata()`, it's that you shouldn't ever need to!

Comment: So basically you're saying: Only use wp_reset_postdata() and the codex has a poor example? (If you want to do it correct)

Comment: The codex may change, so I'm going to avoid making absolute statements about it which may become incorrect. It has an example a `WP_Query()` loop which uses `wp_reset_query()` and unnecessarily so. It could use `wp_reset_postdata()` instead, but no harm is done. It also has a `query_posts()` example where it does, and **must**, use `wp_reset_query()`. As noted in the codex, though this is a bad example and 'not recommended' in the sense that `query_posts()` should never be used.

Comment: Do I need to reset the query if I loop through the query within a foreach loop?

For ex:

$sol_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'solution',
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'lang'  => pll_current_language(),
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);

$solution_posts = new WP_Query($sol_args);
$solution_posts = $solution_posts->get_posts();

<?php foreach ($solution_posts as $solution_post) { ?>
<?php } ?>

wp_reset_postdata()