# WP_Query, pre_get_posts and offset

Tags: wp-query, pre-get-posts, offsets

I can't get my head around, why `offset` seems to be forwarded from custom `WP_Query` in page template to the main query further down?!

From my **functions.php**

```php
/**
 * ::: Filter 'Custom Post Type' Archive Main Query :::
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_cpt_posts' );

function filter_cpt_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' ) ) {
        return $query;
    } 
    else { // on is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' )
        $query->set( 'offset', '1' );
        return $query;
    }
}
```

From my **archive-cpt.php**:

```
<?php
    $loop_recent_post = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt',
        'posts_per_page' => 1, // number of posts to display
        'offset' => 0
    ) );

    if ( $loop_recent_post->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop_recent_post->have_posts() ) { 
            $loop_recent_post->the_post(); 
?>

<!-- HTML Code -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

and further down:

```
<?php 
    //query_posts( 'post_type=cpt&offset=1' ); //Get rid of `query_posts`
    if ( have_posts() ) { 
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
?>
```

Posts start in main query with `offset=0`.

Why?

PS: Yes,

- I've read [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) -- that's the origin of why I came to alter query via `pre_get_posts`,
- and `wp_reset_query()` doesn't make a difference after `WP_Query`, I've followed [this rec](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144343/wp-reset-postdata-or-wp-reset-query-after-a-custom-loop).

Answer (score 1):

It helps to write problems down.

After I haven't used `pre_get_posts` extensively, I focused too much on that area for the cause, but it was the `if` clause.

Changed to

```
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' ) ) {
    return $query;
} 
elseif ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' ) ) { // on is_post_type_archive( 'cpt' )
    $query->set( 'offset', '1' );
    return $query;
}
else {
    return $query;
}
```

Everything is working fine. I like `pre_get_posts`.