# Using PHP for background-image property

Tags: php, css

I'm building a gallery page for a website and want to use the images from post types as background images with lightboxes. The code im using currently is this:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
        <?php
            $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'sympathy-flowers',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
                ));
        ?>
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="b33" style="background-image: url("<?php echo the_field('image'); ?>;">
            <p>Hello World!</p>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

When I refresh the page, it brings through the p tag, however the background-image is not working, how would I fix this?

Problem has since been fixed.

Comment: you missed closing the bracket for `url(` it should be `?>);">`

Comment: Just a quick heads up I think you should be using `wp_reset_postdata();` instead of `wp_reset_query();` the reason for this can be found here [wp_reset_postdata(); or wp_reset_query(); after custom loop](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144344/85776)

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems you are using ACF. The you need not echo `the_field()` only echo `get_field('')`

Comment: Also could how did you set up the AFC image field , did you select URL or array or ID?

Comment: I'm using custom post types for this, it runs off an archive.

Comment: `the_field()` is of acf isn't it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, if I put the php code where the p tag is, it pulls through all the images, it just doesn't work when I put the php code into the background-image property.

Comment: `<div class="b33" style="background-image: url('<?php  the_field( 'image' ); ?>')">`
try replacing you're existing code  with this code

Comment: Didn't work, it doesn't even pull through the p tag when I add the code.

Comment: Could you confirm if the function `the_field()` is of acf or of a custom origin

Comment: the_field() is acf, just checked

Comment: could you run `print_r(get_field('image'))` and let me know if you get an array of sort or just a normal string or int value

Comment: Has been solved, not entirely sure what happened, put in this code:         <div class="b33" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field( 'image' ); ?>')">

Comment: I formatted you're initial code as it was missing a `(` and there were some issues with the `"`
may be that worked

Answer (score 0):

You could get done by adding code as below.

```
<div class="container" style="background-image: url('<?php echo  get_field('image',get_the_ID());?>)'">
```

Comment: Does this mean that I'd have to pull through each image manually, there's at least 15 different images that I need.

Comment: @Quarismo: Please check updated code. If not work then try to debug first by put var_dump(get_field('image')); to get exact idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please check first what you get from `the_field('image');`

```
$img = get_field('image');

var_dump( $img );
```

Maybe it's just output array with id, url, width, ..

and fix html

```
  <div class="b33" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('image');?>);">
```