# Running Filter or Shortcode Before Query Prevents Excerpt from Showing

Tags: shortcode, query, excerpt, get-the-id

I've been wrestling with some code cobbled together for a function I found, first published circa 2009 and my inexperience with PHP has me at a loss.

The function is designed to count episodes in a podcast category, thus:

```
function Get_Post_Number($postID){
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$postNumberQuery = new WP_Query(array (
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'ASC',
'post_type' => 'any',
'category_name' =>'podcast-episodes',
'posts_per_page' => '-1'
));
$counter = 1;
$postCount = 0;
if($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) :
    while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
        if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
            $postCount = $counter;
        } else {
            $counter++;
        }
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
$wp_query = $temp_query;
return $postCount;
}
```

As far as I can tell, this works fine. I created a shortcode to return the value in the query, which then resulted in the excerpt not showing. I then created a filter to do the same and the result was the same. No excerpt. Here I'll just post the shortcode:

```
/**
* Create shortcode to display Episode count.
*/

function episodeNo() {
    $epID = get_the_ID();
    $epNumber = Get_Post_Number($epID);
    echo 'Episode ' . $epNumber;
    }
add_shortcode('episode','episodeNo');
```

Here is my query:

```
$args = array(
                    'posts_per_page'        => 3,
                    'category_name'         => 'podcast-episodes'
                );  
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
                // The Loop
                if ( $query->have_posts()){
                    echo '<ul class="entries">';
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        echo '<div class="entries-post">';
                        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                        echo '<h1 class="entries-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
                        echo '</a>';
                        do_shortcode('[episode]');
                        echo '<div class="entries-excerpt">';
                        the_excerpt();
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';

                }
                /* Restore original Post Data */
                wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now, if the shortcode runs *before* the_excerpt, it correctly displays the episode number but no excerpt.

**Title**

Episode 11

**Title**

Episode 10

**Title**

Episode 9

If it runs *after* the the_excerpt, it correctly displays the excerpt and the episode number:

**Title**

This week I cry into my coffee

Episode 11

**Title**

This week I approach a new design project

Episode 10

**Title**

This week I mostly play video games

Episode 9

Unfortunately, the design is such that episode must be displayed before excerpt.

The exact same occurs were I to use a filter that performed the same duty as the shortcode.

Does anyone have any idea why the_excerpt fails to display if called after this shortcode? I'm certain it's the way in which the episode number is calculated or returned, but know too little to correct it myself. Believe me, I have attempted to. At length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to rest the post data before return the $postCount. Before return it, add the follow:

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

--

There is a difference between `wp_reset_query()`and `wp_reset_postdata()`, as explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144343/wp-reset-postdata-or-wp-reset-query-after-a-custom-loop).

- `wp_reset_query()` - ensure that the main query has been reset to the original main query.
- `wp_reset_postdata()` - ensures that the global $post has been restored to the current post in the main query.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't change anything, assuming you mean:  '
         }
 endwhile; endif;
 wp_reset_query();
 $wp_query = $temp_query;
 wp_reset_postdata();
 return $postCount;
}'

Comment: It's showing the the excerpt  from the last post queried by the shortcode. You need to `setup_postdata`again after the shortcode so wordpress understand it's back to the first loop. In the loop, after the `do_shortcode` and before the `the_excerpt();`, add the following `setup_postdata($query->post);`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extra assistance here. That last piece solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your code a lot, by just using:

```
$episode_number = ( $query->found_posts - $query->current_post );
```

in the loop as the *episode's* number.

So you don't need that problematic `Get_Post_Number()` function and there's no need to use a special shortcode for this.