# WordPress get_template_part() function not working

Tags: theme-development, themes, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using `get_template_part()` function on my file (`page-home.php`) like
[page-home.php](https://gist.github.com/cannelflow/ef4be1a80bdde065265af69fdc56296c) and it is working fine until I called it 5 times on the same file (`page-home.php`) but when I called it 6th times like

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'project' ); ?>
```

data from advanced custom field plugin is not showing, but the data from `Custom Post Type UI` plugin is showing correctly and if I delete any of the above `get_template_part()` the data from `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'project' ); ?>`is showing correctly.

Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: content-project.php code looks like https://gist.github.com/cannelflow/bc78645a8b191448592ec51ec74c5d0d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is in the `content-project.php` file.
Whenever using `WP_Query()` make sure to use `wp_reset_postdata();` Additional details can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144343/wp-reset-postdata-or-wp-reset-query-after-a-custom-loop)

Comment: i didn't used wp_reset_postdata(); in any of the above file where i should try putting that i tried just after  <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'project_feature', 'orderby' => 'post_id','order'=>'ASC' ) ); ?>  not showing any difrence

Comment: i figured it out just after closing the loop working fine now

Comment: If you have multiple `new WP_Query()` in a single page make sure to use wp_reset_postdata();