# Bug with post titles

Tags: posts, media, get-the-title

My post titles are displaying the title of the media (image) rather than the title of the post.

- WP V4.8
- using postgrid for posts; deactivated this, issue still
  occurs
- deactivated current theme; issue still occurs
- reset permalinks
- using wordfence to scan for errors; removed old WP files but issue
  still occurs.

Scratching my head on this one...any ideas??? Or is this a bug in V4.8?

Comment: Give us more details. To start, give us a link to your website.

Comment: http://www.healthyfoodsolutions dot co dot uk/business/blog/

Comment: Which page you're talking about? Is it a front page, or some other page? Please provide URL to it. So far it looks ok.

Comment: Are you talking about the html `<title>` or something within page content? Either way I'm not seeing the issue on the site you provided. Maybe you're cached?

Comment: i'm talking about the tittle of the image i.e image.jpg being used as the post title href link and title text are affected. I've provided a URL above but you'll have to replace the dot with .co.uk as i don't wan't to get spammed/hacked!

Comment: Have cleared the site cache and tested on another device...same issue!

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://shrinktheweb.snapito.io/v2/webshot/spu-ea68c8-ogi2-3cwn3bmfojjlb56e?size=800x0&screen=1024x768&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.healthyfoodsolutions.co.uk%2Fbusiness%2Fblog%2F

Comment: What are your *Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays*? Your screenshot refers to the page of posts which I cannot find.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz the screen shot is of the url above! My reading settings are set to "latest posts" so my posts appear on my home page and my blog page.

Comment: Ok. Got it now!

Comment: Good! I'm doing some debugging...I've removed the featured image and embedded image from my post and the title and link have reverted back to the default! Bizarre!

Comment: If I add the featured image to the post, the post uses the image's title as the post's title again. Eh?

Comment: Just disabled all my plugins and it works as normal...so must be a buggy plugin or conflict.

Comment: Yes, it looks ok now. Happy hunting for an offending plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to using custom query/loop stuff after the main query and not calling either `wp_reset_postdata()` or `wp_reset_query()` after you're done. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144343/wp-reset-postdata-or-wp-reset-query-after-a-custom-loop#answer-144344) for more detail on which to use.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled all plugins and posts reverted back to normal behaviour. Re-enabled plugins and all ok. Very odd...no obvious cause/conflict. Must have been a dodgy update or conflict somewhere.