# wordpress query in header won't reset and corrupts other loops

Tags: wp-query, loop

In a template part in my header, I have the following code:

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'weather_today','orderby'=>'ID','order'=>'ASC','posts_per_page'=>1);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$html;
if ($query->have_posts()){
$posts = $query->posts;
foreach($posts as $post) {
$html = $post->post_content;
}
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

My understanding is that `wp_reset_postdata` is what I need to reset the query, according to this answer: [wp_reset_postdata() or wp_reset_query() after a custom loop?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144343/wp-reset-postdata-or-wp-reset-query-after-a-custom-loop)

I tried `wp_reset_query()` as well but neither works, as my other template parts are getting affected by the header code. As an example, when I do my `single.php` template and do this:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_title();
endwhile;
```

I get the `weather_today` post type title, not the `single.php` post.

I got around this in my `category.php` by doing this:

```
$current_category_id = get_query_var('cat');
$current_category_obj = get_category($current_category_id);
$args = array('orderby'=>'ID','order'=>'DSC','posts_per_page'=>8,'cat'=>$current_category_id);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And then looping through, but I don't want to keep moving around the issue that my header query isn't resetting. I don't know a similar work around for `single.php` and it seems unideal to do a `WP Query` on a template file that is supposed to instantiate it's own query - like how `single.php` should pick up on the post that is single given the url, or however it works internally.

How do I do the query I need in my header and still be able to have the other theme/template files work as expected?

Comment: I'm curious, rather than doing a standard query loop you used a `foreach` on `$query->posts`, this is very unusual, can you explain? I also noticed you reused the global `$post` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here.

First, you're not using the loop properly. Instead of the `foreach` use `while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); //etc`.

Secondly, in using `foreach($posts as $post)` you are overwriting the global $post variable, so if you really must use foreach then use a different variable name!